# How to make mouseup fire anyehere?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop script that is relatively functional. However, I want to be able to trigger mouseup anywhere on the screen. Is there a way to trigger mouseup outside of the window, or outside of the current element? I know this is possible and I've seen other questions like this. I wanted to find a way in vanilla Javascript to detect mouseups like this.

```js
document.onmousemove = mouseCoords;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var cl1= false;
var divid;
var offs1;
var offs2;
var topPos;
var leftPos;

function mouseCoords(e) {
    x = e.x
    y = e.y
    if(cl1 === true){
  document.getElementById(divid).style.top = topPos + (y-offs1) + 'px';
  document.getElementById(divid).style.left = leftPos + (x-offs2) + 'px';
 }
}
var drag = function(i, cas) {
 divid= i
 switch(cas){
  case 1:
   var rect = document.getElementById(divid).getBoundingClientRect();
   leftPos = rect.left;
   topPos = rect.top;
   offs1 = y;
   offs2 = x;
   cl1= true;
  break;
  case 0:
   offs1 = 0;
   offs2 = 0;
   cl1= false;
  break;
 }
}
```

```css
#block{
  width: 100px; z-index: 20; height: 50px; background-color: blue; position: fixed; user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; 
}
.drag{
width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">mouseup doesn't trigger over me!</div>
<div id="1" class="drag" onmousedown="drag(1, 1)" onmouseup="drag(1, 0)"></div>
```

Comment: add event listener for mouseup to `document`

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept it

Comment: I will, but instead of calling `mouseCoords` I would have to call `drag(null, 0)`

Comment: My bad, I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`document.addEventListener("mouseup", drag(null, 0));`
for `mouseup`,

and this code for `mousedown`.

`document.addEventListener("mousedown", drag(null, 1));`

Basically, `document.addEventListener` works for the whole window. `"mouseup"` tells the script that the event is a `mouseup`, and the final bit is the function to be executed (drag(1, 0))